# Search for latest newsfeed posts with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, search, newsfeed

I'd like to show the latest newsfeed posts on my intranet homepage. How can I search for the latest posts using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where your news posts are.

1. If it is all coming from a single list then go for JavaScript and List API.
2. However for multiple sources query use [Search API's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn423226.aspx).You can query against a result source. Check this [Link](http://www.techmikael.com/2015/01/how-to-query-using-result-source-name.html)
3. But the best approach i would suggest would be to go for Search Results web part and use display templates to display your results. [Link](https://melcher.it/2014/12/z-create-display-template-sharepoint-2013-search-visualize-property-itemdocument/)

Comment: Remember: Search is indexed, so won't return the latest Posts... It will return the latest **indexed** Posts.. so the newest one retrieved can be x minutes to several hours (worst case on SharePoint Online) old. So option #1 gets you the latest for sure

Comment: The posts are in the newsfeeds on various site collections. What is need is something like the newsfeed on the mysite.